# I am working with javaFX 8, I want a way to prevent the user from accessing the parent form when the child form is still open

Tags: javafx-8

loading the fxml form to show on the screen

```
Stage mainStage = new Stage(); 
    try {  
        Parent main = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        Scene scene= new Scene(main);

        //getting the css style sheet              
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.setTitle("HUB KB.S CO. LTD");
        mainStage.setMaxHeight(530);
        mainStage.setMaxWidth(450);
        mainStage.setMinWidth(400);
        mainStage.setMinHeight(500);
        mainStage.setTitle("HUB KBS INVENTORY"); 
        mainStage.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
        mainStage.show();               

        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }
```

I want a way to prevent the user from accessing the parent form when the child form is still open

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code you posted is displaying the "child form", just do

```
mainStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

before calling `mainStage.show()`.

Comment: thank you!! I have tried it and it worked. I am very grateful

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative - if you have several stages and need to be modal to just one, you can do the following.

```
mainStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
mainStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
mainStage.show();
```

This will make the child window modal to a single window and not the entire JavaFX Thread.

Comment: I tried using this to call the child form   and it throws an exception  Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: okay.. I will read more about it .Thanks a lot. very grateful